# What I receive with DatagramPacket?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, udp

If I use DatagramPacket class I can send and receive udp packets.
Ok, but, can I be sure that I will receive only packets from the address I am sending packets to? Or I can receive udp packets on that (randomly assigned) port from any address?
If so, I have to check the origin of every received udp packets and ignore not interesting packets.

Answer (score 1):

The sending and receiving is done through `DatagramSocket` and not `DatagramPacket`. A `DatagramSocket` can send data to arbitrary peers and receive data from arbitrary peers if it is not connected. To make sure that a DatagramSocket can only communicate (i.e. send and receive) with a single peer use `DatagramSocket.connect`.